# Protractor Selenium Hub address

Tags: npm, gulp, protractor, selenium-grid

Is there a way to pass in the address of the Selenium Hub when running the protractor tests e.g. with using `npm run protractor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can pass selenium address while running from command prompt:

```
 protractor --seleniumAddress='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' conf.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be placed inside your conf.js file e.g.:

```
exports.config = {
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   ... 
};
```